# Black screen on boot up no Bios screen

Tags: boot, hardware-failure

After starting the computer the only thing that appears on the screen is a short white line which looks a bit like a cursor except it's not blinking. There was no indication of any trouble when I switched off the computer yesterday. There is no computer logo and I cannot enter BIOS.

What is the most likely component to have failed? Is it something I can attempt to fix myself (assume limited experience)?

Comment: Do the fans and lights come on? Did you change anything recently?

Comment: All lights and fans come on. Haven't made any changes, hardware or software.

Comment: does the monitor recognize the connection? do the disks spin up?

Comment: The monitor powers up when I switch on the computer and displays a white line that looks like a cursor but isn't flashing. There is a sound coming from the computer, I think that might be the disk but not sure how to tell for certain.

Comment: Looks like motherboard failure. Any beeping sounds?

Comment: This has been resolved. It was the graphics card, thanks to everyone who replied.